# How to extract time from json date string using AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, date, momentjs

I want to extract a formatted time string from an incoming json data string but it is necessary to use moment.js in AngularJS to do this?

HTML Code:

```
<div  ng-repeat="event in events | limitTo:1">
    <div class="row spot">
        <span class="orange">When</span><br>
        <span class="large-font">{{event.Date}}</span> <span>{{moment(event.StatrtTime).format('hh:mm:ss a')}}</span><br>
            <span class="orange">Where</span>
    </div>
```

Incoming JSON:

```
events{
  "name":"Party",
   "StartTime":"2/19/2016 7:30:00 AM"
}
```

But this is not working.

Comment: you shoud use the standart angular filter for date
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Comment: I see only a typo: Sta**t**rtTime

Comment: this is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use standart filter for date in angular `{{event.StatrtTime | 'hh:mm:ss a'}}` instead of `moment()`

Answer (score 1):

You could call a function that is in your controller which returns the time using momentjs.

**Assuming your working with controllers**

From the view

```
{{formatTime(time}}
```

In the controller

```
function formatTime(time) {
   var momentTime = moment(time);
   return momentTime.format('hh:mm');
}
```